# Properties of Expected Value of Hermite Polynomial

Tags: probability-theory, power-series, expectation

Are there well know properties of 
\begin{align}
E[ H_n(V)]
\end{align}
where $H_n( \cdot)$ is a Hermite polynomial and $V \in L^n$?

For example if $V$ is Gaussian with variance $1$ and mean $\mu$ than
\begin{align}
E[ H_n(V)]=\mu^n
\end{align}

Also  a reference for beginners would be great.

Thank you

Comment: Are you aware of the following paper : "Polynomial Normal Densities Generated by Normal densities" by Plucinska and Plucinskii, Journal of Mathematical Sciences, Vol 92, N°3, 1998 ? If you cannot get the paper, tell me. Other keywords: Gram-Charlier and Edgeworth decompositions (on this respect , I just found a very intersting presentation on the web by a guy of Lausanne; its title is Heavy_Ions_2009_Michiel_de_Kock_Edgeworth.pdf

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks a lot for the reference. Got the paper. THanks